# Capital H mathematical symbol meaning/name?

Tags: notation

I've been looking for the meaning of a mathematical symbol, and after trying a number of different places, was hoping someone on this board would be able to help! It looks like a capital, standard letter "H" without serifs (one example is included below, in the last line of the text image).

The issue isn't *understanding its meaning,* per se, since (contextually) it seems to mean "of" (as in, 10% of X amount). However, I was hoping to find out if anyone has more information about what this symbol is called, and whether there is any other (and/or deeper) meaning.

[image: Math H Symbol in Context]

That comes from the 8th page [in this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f958/6c94b15f267aaaeb4421920d725e8ae0c154.pdf), and while that's the first time it's used in the text, it appears many more times after that!

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: It seems simply *multiplication* : 10% of $5.000$ is $500$.

Comment: My pdf-viewer shows $\bullet \bullet$ instead of $H$. So perhaps $H$ is not intended. In fact, $\%$ is intended. So its a font problem.

Comment: Never seen that before in my life, but it's clear from the context that you are just taking $10\%$ of what follows.

Comment: Yes, it's not a mathematical symbol at all, just a font problem.  Other font problems occur on subsequent pages.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Whew, that makes me feel a lot better (as opposed to being completely ignorant of some seemingly fundamental notation!) Mind posting it as a short answer so I can accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the file with my pdf-viewer and got a message that this font cannot be displayed and is replaced. Then $10\%$ looked like $10\bullet\bullet$. It might be that your viewer displays it as $10 H$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept it as soon as it'll let me, then I can go and try to find a better pdf viewer!